# Has capital penalty ever been a municipal-level decision?

Tags: cities, death-penalty

I am curious whether municipal-level courts have ever had the authority to impose the death penalty. The sources I have been able to find that deal with the present-day world all discuss it as a matter of state or federal law (and therefore presumably a matter for state or federal courts to decide).

For purposes of this question I want to set aside city-states (for which we have at least [one well-known instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Socrates)); I'm asking about municipalities that are part of a larger political structure.

Comment: During chattel slavery in the American south, capital punishment was delegated below the municipal level.  Without getting enmired in the discussion of the formal definition of "serf", the decision is frequently similarly delegated when the recipient of the penalty is not free.  Might be interesting to examine cases of high justice/low justice.

Comment: Not really sure how you'd define the municipal level, but a German [Landgericht](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landgericht) is certainly below the state level and these courts had the authority to impose the death penalty in the 1920s. See e.g. [Fritz Haarmann](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_Haarmann) or [Joseph Jakubowski](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Jakubowski).

Comment: Also I think your assumption that federal law is only dealt with at federal level courts is flawed. In Germany (and I assume in many other countries) there is only one criminal law for the whole country, but crimes still get dealt with at municipal-level courts.

Comment: And a case where a lowest-level court convicted someone to death in Germany in 1931: https://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/historisches-e-paper/historisches-e-paper-hinrichtung-eines-moerders-16758538.html

Comment: if a lower level municipal court (or a local 1st instance federal judge) gives the death penalty, but it has to be confirmed by a higher level, state or federal court, then it does not count, right?

Comment: It's fictional, but the Gilbert and Sullivan operetta _[The Mikado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mikado)_ is all about municipal level execution.

Comment: so multiple people have provided multiple examples that indicate the answer is "yes". Does that suffice? Is this question answered?

Comment: @MCW I've got the information now, yes. Curiously no one wanted to write an answer...

Comment: What time period are we talking about? If we go back in time, I am pretty sure everyone and their grandmother had "ius gladii" ("right of the sword"). For example in medieval Hungary, a large part of the nobility, many clerics, free cities all that this right beside the king. In Germany, it was a little more strict: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High,_middle_and_low_justice#High_justice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this was common practise in the [Republic of the Seven United Netherlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_Republic). The republic was as loose a [confederation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_and_government_of_the_Dutch_Republic) as can possibly be. Each of the provinces was largely independent, and within those provinces the cities were also largely independent.

A city court could - and did - condemn someone to death, without any interference of higher authorities. [This article explains it](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criminaliteit_en_rechtspraak_in_vroegmodern_Nederland) [in Dutch].